# Converting .py to .exe without libraries

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am working on a python project, it contains PyQt5 based code for GUI and pandas based code for its functions. I tried converting it to an .exe application using pyinstaller but the size of that application came out to be too large. So, now I want to convert only the .py script into .exe without including any of the libraries like pandas, PyQt5, xlsxwriter etc. in it. Those libraries can be installed in the python environment of the PC separately.
Is there any way to do that?
TIA!

Comment: I assume that you constructed a dedicated environment for your project?

PyInstaller pulls in loads of extras that aren't required. If they aren't in your env, they aren't there to be pulled in!

In answer to the question posed, I think your looking at the .spec files and the runtime_hooks=[] entry

Comment: What command you're using?

Comment: I used the following command
pyinstaller -F filename.py
I didn't make a dedicated environment for this project but I installed python for this project only and the libraries that I installed like pandas and PyQt5 are used by this project.
So, would making a dedicated environment still help?

Comment: Also, when I try manually exclude the packages using '--exclude' for example, 
'--exclude pandas', then it throws an error saying "pandas not defined" when I try to run the executable, even when pandas is installed in the PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to convert your .py file to .exe:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'`

Comment: This is most likely what OP already did and resulted in a huge single executable file (because PyInstaller pulls in many unnecessary libraries if it is run outside of a virtual environment). So your above code *would* work but, to meet OP's needs, should be run in an env